# How to make soft-body sphere stay inside concave object?

Tags: soft-body

So, I have a soft body sphere inside a 'maze', (this is just the beginning of it) like this...[image]

The sphere has soft body settings of:

[image]

The maze had settings of:
[image]

However, as soon as I played the animation, the sphere squished and jumped out the back part of the maze... What I wanted it to do was roll down the ledge.

NOTE: This may be a duplicate, but I've looked up around the place and nobody has had the same problem as me (that I've seen).

Comment: "Jumped out the back" indicates the sphere was over lapping with the back of the maze. If it is is not then the simulation resolution is not fine enough and the simulation thinks the tolerances do place the sphere to close to the maze back.

Comment: How would I update (increase) the resolution?

Comment: On the Scene tab under Rigid body settings there is "Steps per second" and "Solver iterations" But be wary, increasing them too much will slow the simulation time significantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The physics solver tries to minimise the work it does by making approximations. You can increase the number of steps the solver will calculate and the number of iterations attempted to improve the detail of collisions.

On the Scene tab under Rigid body settings there is "Steps per second" and "Solver iterations"

But be wary, increasing them too much will slow the simulation time significantly.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Why didn't you make the sphere **active rigid body**? I would have done it. And below is my way of doing the whole anim.

Add a cube; create the maze; give the maze's sides a different material and make it 100% transparent; put the ball inside; play the animation.

Comment: I believe that having a soft-body ball is a requirement of who asked the question (note the title!)

Comment: It wasn't made specific. If it's not, alternative ways CAN be presented and nobody must downvote it.